# Histogram for all column data against one column data from Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I want to display histograms for all columns say total 5 against last column values in one data frame.
So the frame will have 10 histograms for each column against column 6 values.

```
df.hist(column=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
```

I tried to use by attribute but it is producing wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused, a histogram only uses values from 1 column to obtain a distribution of said column. So in reference to your question, the histogram is not the right tool.

Unless column 6 has 2 values and you wish to obtain the histograms from the 5 columns filtered by value 1 and 2, then you can do this:

```
df[df['col6']==1].hist(column=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
df[df['col6']==2].hist(column=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
```

If the above is not the case, and you want to plot the interactions between 2 columns, having a shape similar to a histogram, then what you would need is a bar plot:

```
df.plot.bar(x='col1', y='col6', rot=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [seaborn library](https://seaborn.pydata.org) has many handy functions to quickly create this kind of plots.  One annoyance might be that you need to convert the dataframe to ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data), e.g. using [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

Here is how [`sns.displot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) could be used:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 5), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'])
sns.displot(data=df.melt(var_name='column name'), x='value', col='column name', height=3, kind='hist')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]